# Pandas Plots and Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use plotly as backend in Google Colab to plot from Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 
!pip install plotly==4.14.1

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,3,2], b=[3,2,1])) 
df.plot(backend='plotly') 
fig= df.plot() 
fig.show()
```

When I execute the code above I get the error:

```
ValueError: Could not find plotting backend 'plotly'. Ensure that you've installed the package providing the 'plotly' entrypoint, or that the package has a top-level `.plot` method.
```

I am crearly using !pip to install plotly, So I don't know how to fix it. Any help on how to fix this is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```py
!pip uninstall -y -q plotly; pip install -q plotly
!pip uninstall -y -q pandas; pip install -q pandas

import pandas as pd 
import plotly
pd.set_option('plotting.backend','plotly')

print(pd.__version__, plotly.__version__) # pd 1.2.5 and plotly 4.4.1


def enable_plotly_in_cell():
    ''' Use this function in each cell to show plot in Google Colaboratory.'''
    import IPython
    from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode
    display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''<script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>'''))
    init_notebook_mode(connected=False)


get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', enable_plotly_in_cell)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,30]})

fig = df.plot()
fig.show()
```